# How do you use conditional Activity in ADF in case of failure?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have pretty simple requirement but not sure how this can be implemented in ADF. I have a lookup activity which check certain value in SQL dataset. If it fails I want pipeline variable to be set to one value and if it succeeded then to another and continue on with pipeline. I tried to use "Success/Failure" output of lookup activity but issue is that I can not continue with pipeline since it waits for both activities to finish. I tried to use "IF" activity but I can not figure out how do I detect if previous activity failed to put it as "IF" Condition. What are my choices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your lookup and variable setting on success/fail in their own pipeline.
Then call that pipeline in your main pipeline using ExecutePipeline activity - use the Completed result from ExecutePipeline as the dependency for subsequent tasks so that they run whether the inner failed or not.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62001161/azure-data-factory-handling-inner-failure-in-until-for-activity) for more help.